# Why can't change the admin url in magento1.9?

Tags: admin

```
vim   /var/www/html/magento/app/etc/local.xml 
#change [CDATA[admin]] into [CDATA[admin_guess]]


<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>

rm -rf /var/www/html/magento/var/cache/*
```

Why can't logon into admin with   http://my_host/magento/admin_guess?

```
Error info:
The requested URL /magento/admin_guess was not found on this server.
```

Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at 128.199.80.4 Port 80

[image]

Comment: try with `/magento/index.php/admin_guess`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your app/etc/local.xml

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

frontName has values called admin ad you are trying to load with admin_guess.

either add `<frontName><![CDATA[admin_guess]]></frontName>` or access magento/index.php/admin

P.S. For more Information about changing default admin url to custom admin url you can refer to http://magento-online-tutorials.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-change-magento-default-admin-url.html

Answer (score 2):

In your `frontName` you only have `admin` instead of `admin_guess` e.g:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[admin_guess]]></frontName>
             </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also after doing as Rob and Pradeep have suggested with the "admin" to "admin_guess" clear the cache via FTP just in case.